# Regarding fullscreen color-shifting gradient

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hey there, i am quite new to ActionScript, could you describe how to set up 2 pre selected colors to tween a gradient to instead of "random" ones. My Goal would be to use this class as a dynamic background creater and i would like to have different gradient backgrounds on different pages.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but using the [beginGradientFill and drawRect functions](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Graphics.html) you should be able to do it. If you want to draw a full screen gradient that changes every frame you should be able to use the clear function and redraw it every frame. It doesn't sound good, but I can't find another way really.